# Testing performance of JavaScript vs. Python

Tags: javascript, python, benchmarking

As a high school student, I've recently decided to do a computer science experiment for my school science fair. My hypothesis is that when comparing Javascript and Python on similar programs, JS will perform better on certain common software benchmarking tests. In order to test my hypothesis, I need to write a set of programs in each language that execute common tasks and then test them according to relevant performance benchmarks.

Since I'm new at writing and testing code, I am hoping to get some advice in answer to these questions:

1. What types of (simple) routines would adequately represent the performance qualities of these two languages?
2. What specific tests (speed/CPU and memory usage/etc.) would be the best performance measures?
3. Is there (preferably free) software available to do this kind of benchmark testing?

So far, I've searched Google for general advice about software benchmarking and have found limited practical advice. I just need some initial guidance to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for your tips and suggestions!

Comment: This question is way too broad (and also off-topic) for SO. But maybe [benchmarksgame](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=node&lang2=python3) might be of interest to you?

Comment: They also have a rather detailed description of [how they perform measurements](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/how-programs-are-measured.html)

Comment: Oh, and because I forgot to mention this: Python and JavaScript are languages. On their own they don't do anything. You need to combine them with some way of executing them. e.g.: in the benchmarksgame comparison I linked in my first comment the JavaScript code is executed on Node.js 7.2.1 and the Python code in CPython 3.5.0 (you can find that information at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Check out this site, it has many benchmarks for different languages: https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org

Comment: You can't really make a performance comparison based on the language. You can compare specific implementations but that doesn't really say much about which language has better performance.

Comment: 1) None. Measuring simple routines does not *adequately* represent the performance qualities of programming language implementations. 

2) The best specific tests are those that answer a *specific* need: How fast do we *need* the program to perform the calculation? 

3) You are welcome to use the benchmarks game measurement scripts, here they are -- 

https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/download/benchmarksgame-script.zip

Comment: There's plenty of other background information on the benchmarks game website --

1) https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/why-measure-toy-benchmark-programs.html

2) https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/for-programming-language-researchers.html

3) https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/dont-jump-to-conclusions.html